# Move custom saved amount below the price in Woocommerce simple products

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using the below code to show the saved amount with a percentage just below the price for simple as well as variable products in woocommerce. But it showing the correct format just below the price as in the picture.  but on the sample product page, it shows just about the tile, I changed priority many times but did not achieve the desired result.

The URL is below for a sample product
[sample produt](https://neobery.com/product/100-percent-organic-pure-natural-rosemary-essential-oil-for-hair-skin-body/)

The URL is below for the variable product
[varriable product](https://neobery.com/product/lavender-essential-oil-100-percent-pure-organic-natural-for-hair-skin-body/)

[image]

[image]

```
    // For simple products
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 9 );
function simple_product_saving_amount() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        $active_price  = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );

        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $regular_price * 100 );

        echo '<p id="saving_total_price" style="
     font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%; 
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';
    }
}

// For product variations (on variable products)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variable_product_saving_amount', 12, 3 );
function variable_product_saving_amount( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
        $saved_amount  = $data['display_regular_price'] - $data['display_price'];
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $data['display_regular_price'] * 100 );

        $data['price_html'] .= '<p id="saving_total_price" style="
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%; 
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  ;
">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';

    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:

As you are using Astra theme, try the following revisited code:

```php
// Inline CSS in the header for single product pages
add_action( 'wp_head', 'simple_product_saving_amount_css', 999 );
function simple_product_saving_amount_css() {
    if ( is_product() ) { ?>
    <style>#saving_total_price {font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:40%;background:lightgoldenrodyellow;margin-bottom:1em;}</style>
    <?php }
}

// For simple products
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 10, 2 );
function simple_product_saving_amount( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) && $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        $active_price  = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );

        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $regular_price * 100 );

        $price_html .= sprintf('<p id="saving_total_price">%s: %s (%s)</p>', __("You Save"), wc_price($saved_amount), $percentage.'%' );
    }
    return $price_html;
}

// For product variations (on variable products)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variable_product_saving_amount', 10, 3 );
function variable_product_saving_amount( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
        $saved_amount  = $data['display_regular_price'] - $data['display_price'];
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $data['display_regular_price'] * 100 );

        $data['price_html'] .= sprintf('<p id="saving_total_price">%s: %s (%s)</p>', 
            __("You Save"), wc_price($saved_amount), $percentage.'%' );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Sir, It did not work.

Comment: when inserted your code, the saved amount with percentage shows below the category. I am using the Astra theme, is it due theme

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer code, and it will work with your Astra theme.

Comment: Fine, It worked, Thank you very much for your help and instant support.

Comment: we got the desired result after inserting the above code but One issue arises, the same saved amount with a percentage showing in related products that we do not want

Comment: @MohammadSuhail Ok solved (code updated). The saving amount / percentage will not be displayed anymore in the related products (neither in the upsells). It will be displayed only in the main simple product.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, It works. You Support is awesome, God Bless You

Comment: In the question picture just below the dropdown Clear button with a horizontal line present, I want to remove it. it tried some CSS code but not worked.

Comment: @MohammadSuhail Kindly, for that, please ask a new question, thank you.